# SVG clipPath rendering bug in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, rendering

First of all, look at images:

**Before:**
[image: First version, just after load]

**After:**
[image: Version after manipulations]

Circle is made by dynamic included SVG.

Generated circle SVG code:

http://jsfiddle.net/n9nb7/

**Used libraries:**

jQuery, svgweb

---

**What I do:**

First, after page load, I dynamically created inline SVG with using svgweb for IE8.

Then I fully removed it with it's parent div conteinter.

Then I re-created this SVG code and I get that you see on second picture.

Why I need this: for fully AJAXed site.

---

**Problem:**

You see it on second picture. Problem occupies only in Firefox. Even in IE8 it works normal.

In fact `clipPath` stopped to work.

---

**UPDATE**

Live code http://vseslava.ru/?firefox=1.
My solution you can see here: http://vseslava.ru/ but I need solution without any timeouts.

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't show anything. However it does contain <image> nodes that have a href argument as well as xlink:href. When you recreate things are you recreating the href arguments in the xlink namespace properly?

Comment: I re-create them same way as creating. Yes. Href attribute is for IE8, that doesn't support normal ways.

Comment: @Robert Longson I just read your profile. Where can I post firefox bug of this type? Is there a way of closed (not public) bug posting?

Comment: @Robert Longson Here live code http://vseslava.ru/?firefox=1

Comment: @Robert Longson I posted a bug here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=789470

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the above, I was able to resolve the issue using underscore's `defer` function.

Here's a D3 snippet that works in Firefox (23, at least):

```
var clippedRect = svg.append('rect');

_.defer(function(){
    clippedRect.attr('clip-path', function(d,i){
        return "url(#clippingPath"+i+")";
    });
});
```